# Заполнение колонки в pandas минимальным значением после groupby

Tags: python, pandas, group-by, nan

Путанный заголовок получился, но смысл проблемы вот в чем.
Есть табличка, которая выглядит таким образом:

```
q = pd.DataFrame({'first':[1, 2, 3, 2], 'days':['2019-10-19', '2019-10-20','2019-10-21', '2019-10-21']})
```

Нужно получить вот такую табличку:

```
q1 = pd.DataFrame({'first':[1, 2, 3, 2], 'days':['2019-10-19', '2019-10-20','2019-10-21', '2019-10-21'],
                   'days_min':['2019-10-19', '2019-10-20', '2019-10-19', '2019-10-20']})
```

То есть сгруппировать по первому столбцу, понять какая дата во втором столбце минимальна и именно ей заполнить третий столбец (сгруппированный по первому).

Я делаю вот так:

```
q['days_min'] = q.groupby('first').days.min()
```

Но все заполняется NAN-ами... не понимаю почему так :( Помогите, пожалуйста :(

Comment: [Что делать с ответами на вопрос?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если бы вы посмотрели результат группировки, то увидели бы, что там получается **3** значения. Ведь произошла **группировка** по колонке `first`, в которой **3** уникальных значения. Просто так нельзя эти **3** значения взять и записать в **4** ячейки таблицы (в одной из ячеек обязательно получится `NA`, да и не факт, что эти значения попадут в правильные строки). Нужно делать аналог `SQL JOIN`, чтобы значения попали во все  строки таблицы с соответствующим значением `first`:

```
q1 = q.merge(q.groupby('first').min(), 
             on='first', 
             suffixes=('', '_min'))
q1
```

Вывод:

```
    first   days        days_min
0   1       2019-10-19  2019-10-19
1   2       2019-10-20  2019-10-20
2   2       2019-10-21  2019-10-20
3   3       2019-10-21  2019-10-21
```

Сортировка строк получилась другая, потому что индекс перестроился, но данные получились именно какие вам нужны.

Если хотите сохранить порядок следования строк как в исходной таблице, то нужно делать аналог `SQL LEFT JOIN`, добавив параметр `how='left'`:

```
q1 = q.merge(q.groupby('first').min(), 
             on='first', 
             how='left', 
             suffixes=('', '_min'))
```

Результат:

```
    first   days        days_min
0   1       2019-10-19  2019-10-19
1   2       2019-10-20  2019-10-20
2   3       2019-10-21  2019-10-21
3   2       2019-10-21  2019-10-20
```

Answer (score 0):

Спасибо за предложенный способ. Я на самом деле сделал немного иначе. Я сделал словарь, в котором  каждому first сопоставил days.min(), а потом просто прошелся map:

```
fill_dict = q.groupby('first').days.min().to_dict()
q['days_min'] = q.first.map(fill_dict)
```

Сработало.